# indistinguishable active tab in gnome terminal

Tags: linux, bash, gtk, gnome, gnome-terminal

I am running Gnome 2.30.2 and Gnome Terminal 3.0.1 on my Debian Sid and recently the active tab became almost indistinguishable from other tabs. It is actually the same colour. Changing the themes didn't help much and only using high contrast theme makes a difference which is the theme I would rather not use.

Have been experimenting with ~/.gtkrc-2.0 script but that does not seem to work at all even after restarting X-Server.

```
style "gnome_terminal_notebook"
{
    #fg[NORMAL] = "#00ff00"
    bg[NORMAL] = shade (1.25, "#3c3b37")
}

widget "*TerminalWindow.*.GtkNotebook*" style "gnome_terminal_notebook"
```

Can anybody shed some light on how to make the active tab more distinguishable?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/indistinguishable-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal for the way to customize the appearance (it seems to be a bug, but still not fixed in 2015...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnome-terminal-3.x uses Gtk+3, so changing the Gtk+2 theme indeed does not change the look of your gnome-terminal. There's no Gtk+3 theme switcher except for the Gnome3 tool yet afaik, so you're probably pretty much stuck with the look of it.
An alternative would be downgrading to gnome-terminal-2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Adwaita theme is a GTK3 theme compatible with GTK2. He is in the package `gnome-themes-standard:3.0.2-1` If you don't want to change your theme, you can use Adwaita only for the controls:

```
$ gnome-appearance-properties
Customize
Controls
```

And choose Adwaita. Controls will change your buttons, toolbars, windows list ... AND tabs appearance.

http://lists.debian.org/debian-gtk-gnome/2011/06/msg00015.html